# tumblr on a rails subdirectory on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, blogs, tumblr

If I use tumblr's subdomain feature with rack reverse proxy middle ware will I get the seo benefits of having a blog at site.com/blog over blog.site.com?

Are these articles the right guide for this?

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains

http://bindle.me/blog/index.php/304/rack-middleware-for-seo-fun-and-profit

---

Also this site will be hosted at heroku using zerigo for dns is that where I would point the cname to blog.site.com from?

Comment: did you ever find out if this get your site the SEO content benefits of your tumblr posts?

Comment: I don't get enough traffic to really be able to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you haven't already, enable Zerigo for Heroku (steps available in the custom domain heroku post you referenced):

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains

You may have to wait a couple of days to get your dns propagated through zerigo if you haven't gone through the process already.

Second, go to your heroku dashboard,

dashboard.heroku.com/apps

select the app you want to modify, select zerigo and then select the configure button.  This takes you to the zerigo site.

Third, add a CNAME record in Zerigo.  Set "Host" to subdomainname.yourapp.com.  Set "Data" to domains.tumblr.com and save.

Wait ten minutes for the change to take effect.  Then go to subdomainname.yourapp.com - if it goes to a tumblr error page you are in business.

Login to your tumblr dashboard, choose settings, and check "custom domain name", pointing to subdomainname.yourapp.com.  Select test app.  Should be ready to go rather instantaneously.